# Google Maps ---dynamic map

Tags: google-maps

Please help me create a dynamic google map for a real estate website.

Ex. a user will add a house which is located at city1. it will be saved on the map.
    a user will add a house which is located at ctiy2. it will be saved on same map.

a combined map of all houses and an individual map.

and when i click on the dart on the map it should forward me to the house link.

how to do these? please help me.

Comment: What language?  What have you tried?

Comment: php with mysql database. can you help me? i can only do it when it's a single location and just copying the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need web site with form that will allow user to enter coordinates/address of places.
After form processing you should put those locations in database.
Then, while loading page - you will need to iterate through all this places and put them on map as markers. Add click action to markers to direct to specific pages

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { } )
```

I assume you have basic knowledge of Google Maps API. If not - look for google.maps.Marker